Magento2.4.7: How to Clear/Delete outdated Cookies?
Problem:
We have discovered that when we start getting a large amount of cookies/data, users are getting errors or undesired issues or, in some cases, getting a 400 error.
We need to implement some code that forcibly dumps the user's on-site cookies. This can be after X days/hours, X number of visits, or when it gets to a certain MB.


app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="Vendor_Module::js/cookie-manager.js" />
    </head>
</page>


app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/cookie-manager.js

require([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    "use strict";

    return function () {
        /**
         * Sets a control cookie to track metadata
         */
        function setControlCookie() {
            const controlData = {
                createdAt: Date.now(),
                visits: 1
            };
            document.cookie = "controlCookie=" + JSON.stringify(controlData) + ";path=/";
        }

        /**
         * Clears all cookies
         */
        function clearAllCookies() {
            $.each(document.cookie.split(";"), function (_, cookie) {
                const name = $.trim(cookie.split("=")[0]);
                document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;path=/";
            });
            console.log("All cookies have been cleared.");
        }

        /**
         * Checks cookie conditions (size, age, visits)
         */
        function checkCookies() {
            const controlCookie = $.grep(document.cookie.split(";"), function (cookie) {
                return $.trim(cookie).startsWith("controlCookie=");
            })[0];

            const ageLimitMs = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
            const visitLimit = 50;
            const sizeLimitKB = 4;

            if (controlCookie) {
                const data = JSON.parse(controlCookie.split("=")[1].trim());
                const now = Date.now();
                data.visits += 1;
                const totalSizeKB = document.cookie.length / 1024;
                if (
                    (now - data.createdAt > ageLimitMs) ||
                    (data.visits > visitLimit) ||
                    (totalSizeKB > sizeLimitKB)
                ) {
                    clearAllCookies();
                    setControlCookie();
                } else {
                    document.cookie = "controlCookie=" + JSON.stringify(data) + ";path=/";
                }
            } else {
                setControlCookie();
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log("Checking Cookies...!");
            checkCookies();
        });
    }
});


You should be able to control the lifetime of the cookie from magento itself using the appropiate configuration section as described on the docs
Make sure you are not having this value on 0 which might indicate infinite time.
